# Error 2858 : Why images (background and banner) from my MSI installer are not print in 32Bit - it's ok for 64Bit?

Tags: image, wix, 32bit-64bit

I'm still learning how to make a good installer. I'm using `WIX` - windows installer xml.

I create a `product.wxs` with a UIRef : Mondo.

I change the background and banner images with :

```
    <!-- Install layout custom - change the image in the installer  -->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="images\background.jpg" />
    <!-- Install layout custom - change the logo in the banner-->
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="images\banner.jpg" />
```

I tested it on a `32 Bit` environment and it's not working. However, I ran it for a `64 Bit` and ran it on a 64 Bit environment and It's working.

What can I do to have the same behavior on `32 Bit` and `64 Bit`?

Thanks In Advance for your help!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the install run but you have no images? Does the install fail to run at all? Did you compile for 64-bit? Did you try compiling for 32-bit (x86)?

Comment: Hi Brian, Not working mean the install run but I do not have images (it's blank). The install success to run. I compile it for 32Bit (x86) I do not have image on a 32 Bit environment. I tried to run it on a windows 7, I read something about GIF are not available on a win7 32Bit but nothing about JPG. I tried with BMP too without success. When I compile for a 64 Bit and run it on a 64 Bit environment : it's working. It's a strange behavior.

Comment: I've found one error in the log (error for 32Bit - 64 Bit is ok): `DEBUG: Error 2858:  The data for the bitmap Bitmap is not valid` I took a look on Internet, I've found nothing yet. _For all, I print the log by taping this command line : `msiexec \i myapplication.msi \l*v log.txt`_